# Rewriting example.com/section.php?username=xyz to example.com/xyz/section

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Using the following `htaccess`, I have been able to rewrite `example.com/profile.php?username=xyz` to `example.com/xyz`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1
```

Adding the following to the above,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/section$ section.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/section/$ section.php?user=$1
```

did not resolve `example.com/section.php?username=xyz` to `example.com/xyz/section`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm going to test now, but just a hunch; have you tried escaping (add a "\" without quotes) before your /? / is a regex special char.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The manner of speaking would rather be the opposite: The rules you showed are to rewrite requests like `/xyz` internally to `/profile.php?username=xyz` and *not* vice versa.

Now if you want to rewrite requests like `/xyz/section` internally to `/section.php?username=xyz` where `section` and `xyz` are variable, try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $2.php?user=$1
```

Comment: @pranav_kavi: These two rules are intended to replace your mentioned rules; the optional `/` at the end (`/?$`) will match both.

Comment: It is better to statically declare rewrites unless all dynamics are declared to a static file. If the users have an upload directory or something similar, it will not be accessible if you dynamically rewrite user/directory (provided that their directory is something like user/upload). Also, directories that don't exist will give $2.php not found errors (if you're pointing it to a dynamic file name).

Comment: @RageD: The expression `[^/]+` can easily be replaced by a more specific expression like an alternation (`foo|bar|…`).

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it works. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/section$ section.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/section\/$ section.php?user=$1
```

All I did was escaping the `/` in the URL since `/` is a regex delimiter.

Comment: No, `/` is not a special character in regular expressions. Only some language have a literal regular expression syntax where `/` are the indicators/delimiters. But that’s not apply to Apache’s mod_rewrite.

Comment: The section page did appear but with out any of the css or js files loaded

Comment: @pranav_kavi The CSS is being sought in your "/user/section" probably which is why it's not being found. I would put the full URL path to your CSS files, images, and js files so that this error does not occur. You can do this with PHP.

Comment: @Gumbo - Ah yes, you're right! My mistake, but it does apply to Apache I believe.

Comment: @RageD: An even if it would apply to Apache, then the second `/` should be escaped too.

Answer (score 1):

To look for static files (images, css) in the right directory without having to write the file address, do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Before writing the code suggested by RageD

(Sorry, should have posted it as a comment but I needed newlines)

Comment: I tried adding the above along with the code suggested by RageD. I am still losing the CSS and JS files.

Comment: The sequence is: 1) rewrite engine on; 2) this; 3) raged code. anyway, can you give me the addresses to your css file, as in the generated HTML?

Comment: It was <link href="account.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. but once I changed it to <link href="/account.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />, the css  file has loaded.Same holds for images and the js files.

Comment: Conclusion: the section page was not coming out properly was because the paths to the css/js/image files were not preceded by a /. The rewrite rule mentioned for the section page was right all along. Thanks alot for your help